# How to capture user input text box value if he waits more than 3 seconds nothing entering and storing it in db using JScript

Tags: javascript

I'm developing an application in that i need to capture user input from text box, if he stops typing for more than 3 sec. means we need to capture that text using javascript and need to store it in mysql db... plz help me out of this?

```
 Thank you.....
```

Comment: you can create a timedout javascript function based xhr/ajax call that saves the information every 3 seconds..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach events to the input (e.g. keyup, keydown, keypress). There you will set up a setTimeout with a callback. Of course the timeout ID will be stored in a var (e.g. window.type_timeout). The setTimeout callback will do what you want ater those 3 seconds of inactivity.

You can start here. E.g.(using jQuery):

```
$('input').on('keyup',function(){
    if( window.type_timeout ) clearTimeout( window.type_timeout );
    window.type_timeout = setTimeout( do_stuff , 3000 , this /* extra data */ );
});

function do_stuff( input ){ /* do your stuff */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout. W3 schools has a pretty good reference on [JavaScript timing](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

```
<script>
    inputSaveTimeout = null;
    function DoSomething() {
        window.clearTimeout(inputSaveTimeout);
        alert('I just did something');
    }
    function Updated(e) {
        window.clearTimeout(inputSaveTimeout);
        inputSaveTimeout = setTimeout(Save, 3000, e.value);
    }
    function Save(data) {
        alert('Saved: ' + data);
    }
</script>
<input type="text" onkeydown="Updated(this);" /><input type="button" value="Do Something" onclick="DoSomething(); return false;" />
```